# When the ball collides the paddle2, it didn't bounded at correct position.

Tags: python, pygame

As the code show, when the right of the ball <= the left of the paddle, it will bounded. But it didn't. Here is the code for Ball class which contains all the informations about ball.

```
class Ball:
  def setDim(self):
      self.top = self.y
      self.bot = self.y + self.height
      self.left = self.x
      self.right = self.x + self.width

  # define moveBall(self) to display ball objectives
  def moveBall(self, paddles):
      global score1, score2
      self.setDim()
      if self.x >= 250:
          if (self.left <= paddles[1].right) and (self.right>= paddles[1].left) :
             if ((int(self.top) == int(paddles[1].bot) or int(self.bot) == int(paddles[1].top)) and (self.ax > 0)):
                self.ay = -self.ay
          elif (self.top <= paddles[1].bot) and (self.bot >= paddles[1].top):
               if (int(self.right) >= paddles[1].left) and (self.ax > 0):
                  self.ax = -self.ax
      self.x += self.ax * self.speed
      self.y += self.ay * self.speed
      window.blit(self.ball_surf, (self.x, self.y))
```

I only showed the code piece for the ball collide with the Paddle[1] which is the paddle 2.

Comment: Your post does not seem to include a question. You should edit it so that there is an actual question posed. The question will be easily recognized as it will end with a question mark.

Comment: What do you mean 'it will bounded'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the ball approaches the `paddle[1]` (right paddle), the instance in comes in contact it actually penetrates a bit.  Meaning that `self.right` will be `>=` `paddle[1].left` as expected.  However your code to handle the horizontal bounce is never reached.  This is due to the vertical bounce external `if` condition being met and the horizontal bounce is in an `elif`.  Also since you are comparing `top` and `bot` as exactly `==`, it is likely that the vertical internal `if` condition will not evaluate to True either. Causing nothing to happen.